# Repository, data contract classes and filter requests with arbitrary expression predicate

Tags: .net, repository, application-design

We have the following architecture of data access layer:

1. Class, that is mapped to DB table. Let's say, `Order`. It has property `Status` of type `string`.
2. Data contract class `OrderContract`, that has property `Status` of some enum type. (DB contains string representation of this enum)
3. Entity Framework powered repository, that internally gets `Order`s, converts them to `OrderContract` via `AutoMapper` and returns these `OrderContract`s.

And now we have a task to implement method in this repository, that would be able to query orders using arbitrary criterion (predicate). If repository returns just `Order`, I would add a method like this:

```
public List<Order> FilterBy( Expression<Func<Order, bool> predicate );
```

but unfortunately repository returns `OrderContract`s.

Is there any standard or convenient way to implement such method that would be able to get an expression of `OrderContract` and return `OrderContract`s too?

I can name two ideas we have:

1. Write an expression rewriter, that would translate input expression `Expression<Func<OrderContract, bool>>` into `Expression<Func<Order, bool>>`. But this rewriter would have to know how to convert enum comparisons to string comparisons etc.
2. Create a set of specifications, that would know how to perform different queries (`Select.ById( someId )`, `ByNumber( someNumber )` etc) and would be able to create necessary `Order` expressions.

Comment: I was not able to understand what you want, but you can always write a method which returns IQueryable<T> and then join it with other queries to get desired output. if you meant about writing dynamic predicates you can have a look at LINQkit. Suggestion -  The repository should return the Database objects and then you need to convert them to whatever representation you want in the Business layer.

Comment: I am asking about the best solution for filtering method implementation in the repository, that returns data contract classes and internally works with DAL classes.